# group and count in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have table like this

table1

```
   col1             
    ______
    data1
    data2
    data3             
    data4             
    data5
```

and  table2

```
data1  
_________
data1,data2
data1
data3,data1
data5
data4,data5,data1
data2
```

Can I have query that joins both tables with result two column first column content table1.col1 list and column 2 content count of data that content like first column

```
column1|column2             
_______|_______
data1  | 4
data2  | 2
data3  | 1            
data4  | 1          
data5  | 2
```

For now I use query inside looping in PHP

```
$s="select col1 from table1";
foreach($conn->query($s) as $r);) {
echo "select count(*) from table2 where data1 like '%$r[col1]%' "; 
}
```

If there is any query that can achieve without query inside looping.

***btw I use pdo query helper instead mysql_query, i just write a little code by using mysql_query.***

Thanks.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: you right bro, like my footer, said, i just use mysql_query to shorten my quetsion.

Comment: Post your PDO code. Don't put in obsolete junk that has nothing to do with what you're actually doing. If your PHP code isn't the issue, omit it and focus on the query.

Answer (score 2):

First of all is that you shouldn't keep multiple values in single field (table2) when you need it's values in SQL queries.

Anyway, you can utilize [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) MySQL's function to join both tables and then use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(*)` to get what you need.

```
SELECT table1.col1 as column1, count(*) as column2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN tabl2 ON FIND_IN_SET(table1.col1,table2.data1)
GROUP BY table1.col1;
```

Although there's ready function to do such things, you should keep an eye on performance issues that may occur here.

Comment: it work, thanks man, u save my live, about performance, it not a big deal, couse it only about 1000 data, lol